# Troubleshooting Find Error

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason my code is only returning the "If Find Is Nothing" when I know the values are in there. The values are stored as text in all the sheets in the exact same format (18 digit number with leading zeros).

I was trying to speed up the report loading time by using this instead of VLOOKUPs, but it only gives me "No" and "0" instead of the appropriate answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Note:s and e are the first and last row of the data respectively).

Edit: Using and in sheet VLOOKUP returns the appropriate values.

```
Sub GSLookup(s As Integer, e As Integer)
Dim rng As Range
Dim j As Range
Dim k As Range
Dim rngc As Range
Dim rngm As Range

Worksheets("COOIS").Activate
If Worksheets("COOIS").AutoFilterMode = True Then
      Worksheets("COOIS").AutoFilterMode = False
End If

Worksheets("Mara").Activate
If Worksheets("Mara").AutoFilterMode = True Then
    Worksheets("Mara").AutoFilterMode = False
End If

Worksheets("COOIS").Activate
Set rngc = Worksheets("COOIS").Range("A4:P4")
Set rngc = Worksheets("COOIS").Range(rngc, rngc.End(xlDown))
Worksheets("Mara").Activate
Set rngm = Worksheets("Mara").Range("H4:I4")
Set rngm = Worksheets("Mara").Range(rngm, rngm.End(xlDown))
Worksheets("Scorecard").Activate
Set rng = Worksheets("Scorecard").Range(Worksheets("Scorecard").Cells(s, 4), Worksheets("Scorecard").Cells(e, 4))

For Each j In rng
        Worksheets("Mara").Activate
    If rngm.Find(j, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            j.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0
    Else
            Set k = rngm.Find(j.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            j.Offset(0, 2).Value = k.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
    Worksheets("COOIS").Activate
    If rngc.Find(j, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            j.Offset(0, 3).Value = "NO"
            j.Offset(0, 4).Value = "NO"
    Else
            Set k = rngc.Find(j, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            j.Offset(0, 3).Value = "YES"
            j.Offset(0, 4).Value = k.Offset(0, 12).Value
    End If
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Quick FYI: You must declare each variable individually. `Dim rng, j, k, rngc, rngm as Range`  only sets `rngm` as `Range`, all others become `Variant`. Also, you should always add the worksheet when using `Cells()`, just like you did with `Range()`.  This *probably* is contributing to the unexpected results. Try tweaking that and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I did not know that. Let me try those updates and see if it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BruceWayne , I broke the Dims apart, but I didn't see anyplace where the Cells were not identified. I always used Cells within a Range that was properly defined with the workbook. (Also this did not change the results).

Comment: You have `Set rngc = Range(rngc, rngc.End(xlDown))` with `Range()` not identified, and also you have `Set rng = Worksheets("Scorecard").Range(Cells(s, 4), Cells(e, 4))` with `Cells()` not identified

Comment: @VictorMoraes , So it should be `Set rng=Worksheets("Scorecard").Range(Worksheets("Scorecard").Cells(s,4),Worksheets("Scorecard").Cells(e,4))` ? I'll update the code and see if that fixes the error. I shouldn't need it for the rngc because it is defined as part of rngc. (Unless I'm wrong). AND still no luck. :(

Comment: That's correct and you still need for the `Range()` part as it has nothing to do with what was defined as part of `rngc`. Those are only FYI, though. Unfortunately I'm not able to check your code as of now, I was just pointing out the issues raised by @BruceWayne

Comment: Alright. I updated those, but no difference in output. I think it has something to do with the leading zeroes and numbers stored as text, so I think I'll just try to rewrite it as a Application.Vlookup instead. Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: With your data, just making sure - you **do** have data that would go into the `Else` part, right? In other words, you have made positive that you will find your value? It just keeps latching on to `is Nothing`, when there is actually something?

Comment: Yes, the data is there and can be found with a VLookup.

Answer (score 0):

Switched it to a VLookup and it works just fine.

```
Sub GSLookup(s As Integer, e As Integer)
Dim rng As Range
Dim j As Range
Dim k As Range
Dim ja As String
Dim jb As String
Dim rngc As Range
Dim rngm As Range
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("COOIS").Activate
If Worksheets("COOIS").AutoFilterMode = True Then
      Worksheets("COOIS").AutoFilterMode = False
End If

Worksheets("Mara").Activate
If Worksheets("Mara").AutoFilterMode = True Then
    Worksheets("Mara").AutoFilterMode = False
End If

Worksheets("COOIS").Activate
Set rngc = Worksheets("COOIS").Range("A4:P4")
Set rngc = Worksheets("COOIS").Range(rngc, rngc.End(xlDown))
Worksheets("Mara").Activate
Set rngm = Worksheets("Mara").Range("H4:I4")
Set rngm = Worksheets("Mara").Range(rngm, rngm.End(xlDown))
Worksheets("Scorecard").Activate
Set rng = Worksheets("Scorecard").Range(Worksheets("Scorecard").Cells(s, 4), Worksheets("Scorecard").Cells(e, 4))

For Each j In rng
ja = ""
ja = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(j, rngm, 2, False)
        If ja = "#N/A" Or ja = "" Then
                j.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0
        Else
                j.Offset(0, 2).Value = ja
        End If
jb = ""
jb = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(j, rngc, 13, False)
        If jb = "#N/A" Or jb = "" Then
            j.Offset(0, 3).Value = "NO"
            j.Offset(0, 4).Value = "NO"
    Else
            j.Offset(0, 3).Value = "YES"
            j.Offset(0, 4).Value = jb
    End If
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Just FYI, You don't need to activate the worksheets just to get their ranges, you can "clean" your code a bit by using `With ... End With` blocks, and it is recommended to properly handle the issues instead of bypassing all of them with `On Error Resume Next`